# Entity not found in managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**UPDATE #**3: Another clue...my app wasn't crashing but I set some more breakpoints and stepped into a few and found this:

[image]

It appears to be a bad memory address but I don't know what to do about it. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE #2**: I might have a clue. I put a print statement in each `lazy var` (e.g. print ("I got to lazy var coordinator")) and everyone of the printed the message to the console, EXCEPT, `lazy var context`. Instantiating my CDHelper class should start a chain of events that initialized all of these but for some reason it it skips this one. I've reset the simulator and that doesn't help...

I written some code that will insert some default app data into a Core Data entity called 'Lift' using option binding:

```
if let liftEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lift", inManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context) {
let lift = Lift(entity: liftEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context)
   lift.uid = defaultLift.uid
   lift.liftName = defaultLift.liftName
   print("Inserted New Managed Object for '\(lift.liftName)'")
   CDHelper.saveSharedContext()
      } else {
        // skip setup
      }
   }
```

The problem is that liftEntity is not getting assigned a value so that tells me `NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lift", inManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context)` isn't returning anything. I've checked everything I can think of and I even recreated the data model from scratch so I can see the Lift entity.

That must mean there's a problem with the context. Apologies in advance for the amount of code but I think it's relevant. Here's how that gets created (taken from a book by Tim Roadley, Learning Core Data for iOS with Swift):

```
private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper()
class CDHelper : NSObject  {

    // MARK: - SHARED INSTANCE
    class var shared : CDHelper {
        return _sharedCDHelper
    }

// MARK: - PATHS
lazy var storesDirectory: NSURL? = {
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fm.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    print(urls)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var localStoreURL: NSURL? = {
    if let url = self.storesDirectory?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("LocalStore.sqlite") {
        print("localStoreURL = \(url)")
        return url
    }
    return nil
}()

lazy var modelURL: NSURL = {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    if let url = bundle.URLForResource("oneRepMax", withExtension: "momd") {
        return url
    }
    print("CRITICAL - Managed Object Model file not found")
    abort()
}()

// MARK: - CONTEXT
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
    print (moc)
    return moc
}()

// MARK: - MODEL
lazy var model: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL:self.modelURL)!
}()

// MARK: - COORDINATOR
lazy var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    return NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:self.model)
}()

// MARK: - STORE
lazy var localStore: NSPersistentStore? = {
    let options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [NSSQLitePragmasOption:["journal_mode":"DELETE"]]
    var _localStore:NSPersistentStore?
    do {
        _localStore = try self.coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: self.localStoreURL, options: options)
        return _localStore
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()

// MARK: - SETUP
required override init() {
    super.init()
    self.setupCoreData()

    // Import Default Data
    if let _localStoreURL = self.localStoreURL {
        CDCreator.shared.checkIfDefaultDataNeedsSetup(_localStoreURL, type:
            NSSQLiteStoreType)
    } else {print("ERROR getting localStoreURL in \(#function)")}
}

func setupCoreData() {
    _ = self.localStore
```

I've tried some basic debugging (because I'm pretty new at this) by checking various values at some breakpoints I've set but nothing useful has come out of that. I've reset the simulator as well and still nothing.

Can anybody see where I might be going wrong or provide some tips on how to do a better job of debugging this?

**UPDATE**: After making a copy of my `.xcdatamodel` file on my desktop, I deleted it from my project and then added it back in hoping this might reset something. Unfortunately, it still isn't able to assign a value to `liftEntity`. Using DB Browser for SQLite, I've verified that the entity does exist.

Comment: Put `private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper()` inside your class.

Comment: Thanks @shallowThought, but that's exactly how it's done in the book and the CDHelper class seems to be instantiating itself correctly.

Comment: Sorry. I meant `static private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper()`. I do not know the book, but how I understood it does not work. Set a breakpoint before your "problem line" and see what is `CDHelper.shared` and `CDHelper.shared.context`.

Comment: I tried changing it to `static` but it won't compile and Xcode tells me 'Static properties may only be declared on a type'. I put a breakpoint before it gets to the `if let liftEntity...` and declared a new constant `moc = CDHelper.shared.context`. Then I added   `print("The moc is \(moc)") ` after that. However, as soon as it evaluates `moc = CDHelper.shared.context`, it just stops. It's not hung, it's not stopping on a breakpoint, it's like it just says, "I'm done".

Comment: The error means you did not move it into the class. Is your model called exactly "oneRepMax.xcdatamodel"? You are using Swift 2, right?

Comment: Yes, Swift 2.3 and the model name is 'oneRepMax.xcdatamodeld' (notice the 'd' on the end). If I move private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper() into the class and make it the very first line, then of course it becomes an instance member and I get Instance member '_sharedCDHelper' cannot be used on type 'CDHelper' on the 'return _sharedCDHelper' line.